# Rename method / class on compilation

Tags: java, annotations, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Ran into this problem where I have a handful of obfuscated native dependencies in my program. I'd like to refactor those without creating UnsatisfiedLinkExceptions, refactoring the dll's themselves is not an option at this point. That leaves me with the question is it possible to write something along the lines of an annotation that converts the refactored name to the original obfuscated name?

Comment: Would it be practical to have a set of renamed methods that simply pass arguments through to the obfuscated methods and pass the return values back? `int getValue(string key) { return obFu5c8ed(key); }` etc.